# Comparar carácter de array

Tags: php, ip

Estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora de IP em PHP. Tenho um array de máscara em binário, com 4 posições e em cada posição tem 8 caracteres, quero comparar cada carácter de cada posição para saber se o bit tá setado. Existe alguma função que faz isso? Ou uma outra forma? Pensei em mudar esse array com 32 posições e cada posição ter somente um carácter, mas eu teria que mudar todo meu código.

Comment: Tem como colocar um exemplo de código? Só a descrição ficou um pouco confusa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo escopo da pergunta criei este pequeno exemplo:

```
<?php
$ip_1 = ['11000000', '10101000', '00000001', '00000001'];

//transforma cada octeto em um array de strings
$octeto1 = str_split($ip_1[0]);
$octeto2 = str_split($ip_1[1]);
$octeto3 = str_split($ip_1[2]);
$octeto4 = str_split($ip_1[3]);

verificarBit($octeto1);
verificarBit($octeto2);
verificarBit($octeto3);
verificarBit($octeto4);

/**
para verificar se um bit está setado penso que basta verificar se ele
é igual a 1 (digito binário)
*/
function verificarBit($octeto){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($octeto); $i++){
        if($octeto[$i] === '1'){
            echo 'está setado <br>';
        }else{
            echo 'não setado <br>';
        }
    }
}

/**
eventualmente você pode usar funções de conversão entre bases numericas
Como por exemplo decbin(int numero) que converte de decimal para binario.
bindec(string binario) que converte de binario para decimal

@param $ip array array com quatro octetos ['binario', 'binario', 'binario', 'binario']
@return array [numero, numero, numero, numero]
*/
function converterIpParaDecimal($ip){
    $ip_numerico = [];
    foreach($ip as $octeto){
        $ip_numerico[] = bindec($octeto);
    }
    return $ip_numerico;
}

//testando conversão
$ip_numerico = converterIpParaDecimal($ip_1);
echo '<br><br>';
echo $ip_numerico[0] . '.' . $ip_numerico[1] . '.' . $ip_numerico[2] . '.' . $ip_numerico[3];
```

Não sei quais são as funcionalidades da sua calculadora, mas as funções apresentadas devem dar suporte a implementação.

Comment: Acho que deve funcionar... Vou tentar, mto obrigada! ;)